How can I avoid gaps at the intersection of two lines in TikZ? Or is there a better way to draw them?
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 
\pgfplothandlercurveto
\pgfplotstreamstart
\pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}
\pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{.1cm}{.1cm}}
\pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{0cm}{.5cm}}
\pgfplotstreamend
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\pgfplothandlercurveto
\pgfplotstreamstart
\pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}
\pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{-.1cm}{.1cm}}
\pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{0cm}{.5cm}}
\pgfplotstreamend
\pgfusepath{stroke}

\pgfplothandlercurveto
\pgfplotstreamstart
\pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0.1cm}}
\pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{.1cm}{0cm}}
\pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{0cm}{-.4cm}}
\pgfplotstreamend
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\pgfplothandlercurveto
\pgfplotstreamstart
\pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0.1cm}}
\pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{-.1cm}{0cm}}
\pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{0cm}{-.4cm}}
\pgfplotstreamend
\pgfusepath{stroke}

\pgfplothandlercurveto
\pgfplotstreamstart
\pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0.05cm}}
\pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{-.1cm}{0.15cm}}
\pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{-.5cm}{0.05cm}}
\pgfplotstreamend
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\pgfplothandlercurveto
\pgfplotstreamstart
\pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0.05cm}}
\pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{-.1cm}{-.05cm}}
\pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{-.5cm}{0.05cm}}
\pgfplotstreamend
\pgfusepath{stroke}

\pgfplothandlercurveto
\pgfplotstreamstart
\pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0.05cm}}
\pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{.1cm}{0.15cm}}
\pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{.5cm}{0.05cm}}
\pgfplotstreamend
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\pgfplothandlercurveto
\pgfplotstreamstart
\pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0.05cm}}
\pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{.1cm}{-.05cm}}
\pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{.5cm}{0.05cm}}
\pgfplotstreamend
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



I usually use line cap=round as a workaround.

Try to make the paths continuous at those points and see line join styles. Is there some reason you're using these low level pgf commands rather than a TikZ \draw?

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red] plot[smooth] coordinates {(0,-0.05) (0.1, 0.05) (0, 0.45)} -- plot[smooth] coordinates { (0, 0.45) (-0.1, 0.05) (0,-0.05)} --cycle;
\draw[red] plot[smooth] coordinates {(0, 0.05) (0.1,-0.05) (0,-0.45)} -- plot[smooth] coordinates { (0,-0.45) (-0.1,-0.05) (0, 0.05)} --cycle;
\draw[red] plot[smooth] coordinates {(-0.5,0) (-0.1,0.1) (0.1,-0.1) (0.5,0)} -- plot[smooth] coordinates {(0.5,0) (0.1,0.1) (-0.1,-0.1) (-0.5,0)} --cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Edit:
For completeness, here is the low level equivalent way:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplothandlercurveto
\pgfplotstreamstart
\pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{0cm}{.5cm}}
\pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{.1cm}{.1cm}}
\pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}
\pgfplotstreamend
\pgfsetlinetofirstplotpoint
\pgfplotstreamstart
\pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}
\pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{-0.1cm}{.1cm}}
\pgfplotstreampoint{\pgfpoint{0cm}{.5cm}}
\pgfplotstreamend
\pgfpathclose
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



thanks for your help
